# Alternate index of Array and print numbers using 2 Threads

Tags: java

my exercise is composed of an SharedResource with an array, a NumberGenerator Class and a SumClass.

2 Threads of NumberGenerator and 2 Threads of SumClass.

I have to insert numbers in the array from the SharedResource with both threads of NumberGenerator Class.

This part is done correctly.

My problem is in the run method of the NumberGenerator Class.

These Threads must read alternatively the index of the array, the first thread, lets call it H1, read the index 0-2-4-6... even index, the another one, H2, odd index... But when 1 thread is running the other must wait.

So the output  should be something like this:

Array:[10,35,24,18]

Thread name: H1 - Number:10
Thread name: H2 - Number:35
Thread name: H1 - Number:24
Thread name: H2 - Number:18

My problem resides in the notify and wait methods. When I call the wait method, it automatically stop both Threads even when a notifyAll is present.

I need to just use 1 method, I cant use a evenPrint method and an OddPrint method for example.

Code of my class:

```
public class SumatoriaThread extends Thread{
    String name;
    NumerosCompartidos compartidos; // Object that contains the array.
    double sumatoria; //Parameter used to sum all the numbers 
    static int pos = 0; // pos of the object
    static int threadOrder = 0; //just a way to set the order of the Threads.
    int priority; //Value of the priority
    
    
        
    public SumatoriaThread(NumerosCompartidos compartidos, String name){
        
        this.name = name;
        this.compartidos = compartidos;
        sumatoria = 0;
        priority = threadOrder;
        threadOrder++;
        System.out.println("Hilo " + this.name + " creado.");
    }
    
     public void run() {
         //Array Length
        int length = this.compartidos.length();
        int i = 0;
        
        while (pos < length) {
            //Don't actually know if this is correct.
            synchronized (this) {
                //Just to be sure that the first Thread run before the second one.
                if (priority == 1) {
                    try {
                        priority = 0;
                        //Call a wait method until the next notify runs.
                        this.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(SumatoriaThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                } else {
                    //Even numbers
                    if (pos % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Nombre Thead: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " valor numero: " + this.compartidos.getValor(pos));
                        pos++;
                        //To activate the Thread which is waiting.
                        this.notifyAll();

                        try {
                            //Then I set to wait this one.
                            this.wait();
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Nombre Thead: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " valor numero: " + this.compartidos.getValor(pos + 1));
                        pos++;
                        this.notifyAll();

                        try {
                            this.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(SumatoriaThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow.  A side note...  I believe that it is suggested to implement Runnable instead of extending Thread.  The general thought is that you're not changing the behavior of Thread (via generalization), but implementing the behavior of Thread via its Runnable interface.

Comment: I can't do that, it is a requirement extending Thread :(

Comment: You `synchronized ()` on 'this', which is the thread, and you have multiple threads - synchronized() doesn't do anything unless multiple threads are synchronizing on the same object. Hence, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: and: `while (pos < length)` is invalid - you must not access any field that is being modified from more than 1 thread unless you have established Happens-Before/Happens-After relationship. `synchronized` does this, but only if you sync on the same thing (you don't), and that while clause is outside of it. Hence, the JVM is free to give you local caches or not, at its choice - your code is now like Schrodinger's cat. It works or it doesn't depending on the phase of the moon as far as you know. Solution: Do not read fields unless you're the only thread that touches em, or ensure HB/HA.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'm trying to learn multithreading, I will give it a shot tomorrow, cant do it right now